# How to avoid exceptions thrown in onCompleted to be swallowed

Tags: error-handling, rx-java

Using rxJava 1.1.3, when throwing an exception in the `onCompleted` handling, the `onError`is not called nor is the error propagated to the calling thread. It simply disappears.

As an example consider the following spock test:

```
def "when a onCompleted throws an IllegalStateException, it's handled by the onError handler"() {
    given:
    boolean onErrorCalledFromSubscribe = false
    when:
    Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
            .subscribe(
            Actions.empty(),
            { onErrorCalledFromSubscribe = true},
            {throw new IllegalStateException("I'm behaving badly")})
    then:
    noExceptionThrown()
    onErrorCalledFromSubscribe == true
}
```

The above test fails because onErrorCalledFromSubscribe is never called and is false at the end of the test.

Now, I can imagine that once `onCompleted` is called, `onError` shouldn't be called because either the one or the other should be called.

However, I wonder how do you handle such situations where a `RuntimeException` is called in your `onCompleted` method and you want to handle the error.

Do you simply wrap the `onCompleted` call in a try-catch and handle the error there?

Comment: This seems like a bug in RxJava itself - completely swallowing exceptions shouldn't happen.

Comment: I looked into it and we determined it was a bug: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3885. There's now a PR to fix it in the next version of RxJava: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/3886

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a try-catch in `onCompleted` if you think there might be an exception thrown in there.

As I mentioned in the comments, RxJava should not be swallowing exceptions from `onCompleted` but currently is; still, if you know that there is *going* to be the possibility of an exception, you should just handle it yourself.